# extract data from text file and convert it into df

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

have a txt file with values like this.  how to convert it into dataframe.

tried few ways to remove the white spaces and arranging it in a dataframe.Whole data can be stored in `str` format including date

```
cn No:    9991
PUEN:    S55D
Date :    05/01/2017
Development Name:   
Status: Active
Development Location:   
Address: 3 ADAM PARK #3-3 
Contact No.: 
Name Agent: 
Managing  No.: 5648123
cn No:    4671
PUEN:    T11F
Date :    16/07/2019
Development Name:   MEGA
Status: Active
Development Location:   
Address: 39 WOODLANDS CLOSE,  #01-64, 
Contact No.: 6258 6944
Name  Agent: 
Managing  No.:
```

```
cn No  PUEN     Date        Development Name       Status      Development Location      Address                          Contact No.          Name Agent            Managing No
9991   S55D   05/01/2017                          Active                                3 ADAM PARK #3-3
4671   T11F   16/07/2019     MEGA                 Active                                39 WOODLANDS CLOSE,  #01-64,        6258 6                                   5648123
```

tried this to converting the text file into dataframe

```
f = open('outs.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as e:
    for hostinfo in e.map(lambda x: get_certificate(x[0], x[1]), HOSTS):
        basic_info(hostinfo)

sys.stdout = orig_stdout
f.close()           
f = open("outs.txt", "r")
a=(f.read())
data = a
a=(pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),
              header=None,

              sep="/",
              names=['string'])
     #limit number of splits to 1
  .string.str.split(':',n=1,expand=True)
  .rename({0:'Name',1:'temp'},axis=1)
  .assign(temp = lambda x: np.where(x.Name.str.strip()
                             #look for string that ends 
                             #with a bracket
                              .str.match(r'(.*[)]$)'),
                              x.cn No,
                              x.temp),
          Name = lambda x: x.Name.str.replace(r'(.*[)]$)','cn No.')
          )
   #remove whitespace
 .assign(cn No. = lambda x: x.Name.str.strip())
 .pivot(columns='Name',values='temp')
 .ffill()
 .dropna(how='any')
 .reset_index(drop=True)
 .rename_axis(None,axis=1)
 .filter(['cn No','PUEN','Date','Development Name','status','Development Location','Address','Contact No.','Name Agent','Managing No.'])      
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

So given we have a text file with the content like above

```
import pandas as pd

# Dictionary to store the header and values
my_dict = dict()

# Open the file
with open("./temp.txt", 'r') as file_object: 

    # Read the content
    content = file_object.readlines() 

    # For every row 
    for row in content:

    # Get the header and data
    header, data = row.split(":") 

    # Check if the header is not in dict keys
    if header not in my_dict.keys(): 

        # We add the data with corresponding key
        my_dict[header.strip()] = data.strip()


# Returns a dataframe with the values
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index')
```

Comment: what if there are serveral hundred rows